# Project specific root path environment variable?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables, project, relative-path

In a mixed languages project I have often to refer to configuration files, header files or even Makefiles. I usually use relative paths from the current file. It can be confusing in the case of a YAML configuration file parsed with an external Python script. Should I use the relative path from the configuration file or from the tool used to parse the configuration file? Also if I decide to move my files I have to adjust all the relative paths as well.

To solve this issue I am thinking to use relative paths to the project's absolute root path.

Is there any convention to define a project's path such as:

```
other_file: "$PROJECT_ROOT/src/foo/bar.xml"
```

One possible other solution is to always refer to Git, or define an environment variable for that:

```
other_file: "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/src/foo/bar.xml"

$ export PROJECT_ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```